# How to import jar properly in java?

Tags: java, jar, javac

I am trying to import a jar file. My file "Test.java" contains the line:

"import org.jfugue.*;"

When I run the command "javac -classpath .:jfugue-5.0.9.jar Test.java", I get the error "package org.jfugue does not exist". How do I fix this?

Note: I am using a Mac machine.

Comment: Is `jfugue-5.0.9.jar` in the current directory? If you open it with a ZIP file tool of your choice to see the content, can you see `.class` files in a `/org/jfugue/` folder?

Comment: BTW: You don't *import* a jar file. You add it to the classpath, and you import the classes / interfaces / enums that are inside the jar file. --- Importing a jar file is something you would do in an IDE, where it means to import into the Project, so it is on the classpath of the Project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you inspect the jar file "jfugue-5.0.9.jar", There're no any Class files in the package "org.jfugue.*". Instead it contains some sub packages such as org.jfugue.devices.*, org.jfugue.integration.*, org.jfugue.parser.* etc.

Try something like this,

```
import org.jfugue.devices.*;

public class Hello {

   public static void main (String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hi");

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Starting point

You want to compile code using the contents of a jar file, specifically "jfugue-5.0.9.jar", and you have a "Test" class with an import statement, like this:

```
import org.jfugue.*;
public class Test {
}
```

If you compile that code, you get an error like this:

```
% javac -classpath .:jfugue-5.0.9.jar Test.java                             
Test.java:1: error: package org.jfugue does not exist
import org.jfugue.*;
^
1 error
```

#### What's going on?

You're doing the right steps, mostly, but the import statement isn't correct. Syntax-wise, it's fine, but it does not align with the contents of the jar file. The structure of the jar contents (which you can see by running: `jar tf jfugue-5.0.9.jar`) shows that there *is* a directory for "org/jfugue/", but there are no classes or interfaces there; it's just a directory.

Below is a view of the first 9 lines of jar contents, sorted. It shows several directories without file
contents – "org/" and "org/jfugue/" – but "org/jfugue/devices/" for example has four files present.

```
% jar tf jfugue-5.0.9.jar | sort | head -9
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/jfugue/
org/jfugue/devices/
org/jfugue/devices/MidiParserReceiver.class
org/jfugue/devices/MusicReceiver.class
org/jfugue/devices/MusicTransmitterToParserListener.class
org/jfugue/devices/MusicTransmitterToSequence.class
```

So if you were to change the import statement to "org.jfugue.devices.*" – which would match those four files
("MusicReceiver", etc) – then compilation would work fine (no errors).

```
import org.jfugue.devices.*;
public class Test {
}

% javac -classpath .:jfugue-5.0.9.jar Test.java
%
```

#### Solution

Following
[JLS 7.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1),
you can import each specific class one by one, such as:

```
import org.jfugue.devices.MidiParserReceiver;
import org.jfugue.devices.MusicReceiver;
import org.jfugue.devices.MusicTransmitterToParserListener;
import org.jfugue.devices.MusicTransmitterToSequence;
```

Or following
[JLS 7.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2),
you can import all classes and interfaces matching a wildcard pattern (so
long as there are actually classes or interfaces matching that pattern)
such as:

```
import org.jfugue.devices.*;
```

It's not allowed to import a subpackage, so "import org.jfugue;" (*without* the `.*` wildcard) would not work
(see [Example 7.5.1-3 No Import of a Subpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1) in JLS).